# How to parse String to double with 18 decimal values in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to parse a String with 18 decimal values to double, but it seems double only support 14 decimal values.

For example: “15.123456789101112131”

Comment: Check out this arbitrary precision floating point impl: https://pub.dev/documentation/quantity/latest/number/Precise-class.html

Comment: The `double` type is a *binary* floating-point type, so storing a specific number of *decimal* digits is a bit nonsensical.  If you want to store a specific number of decimal digits, use a type appropriate for that, such as the `Precise` class mentioned above or [`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal).

Comment: Thank you, RichardHeap and jamesdlin, for replying to my question; your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
Precise(
       String value,
       {int sigDigits = 50}
)
```

Constructs an arbitrary precision number from a string.

The precision can be limited by providing the maximum number of significant digits (default is 50).

Examples: Precise('12') Precise('0.1234') Precise('15.123456789101112131') Precise('1.23456789e-6', sigDigits: 4)

[Precise constructor](https://pub.dev/documentation/quantity/latest/number/Precise/Precise.html)